# How to configure selenium RC, Web driver in ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I have an ubuntu server and the script that will open particular website(firefox) and perform some operations and closes.

But always I used to get this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with stacktrace fxdriver.preconditions.visible...
```

Here is some of my code

```
import time
import sys
import json

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb

......
......

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1300, 1000))
display.start()
# Initiate the browser
binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
browser.get('http://somesite.com/')
```

Now When I try to find some element after this getting the above error. Even though added sleep for 30s no use. Can anyone guess whats wrong with this?

Comment: `ElementNotVisibleException` means that the element is present on the page, but can't be clicked because it is either out of the visible screen portion, or some other element hides it (or it is explicitly hidden for example by css). If it is out of screen, you could execute `element.scrollIntoView` as a quick JS before. If it is not your website, but some third party stuff, maybe there is an unexpected overlay on the site covering everything. Try visiting the site with deleted cache/cookies to see if this is the case. Without the website, can't think of other now.

Comment: Ensure your previous actions not making the element to be invisible in your test procedure.  Also make sure the element is visible without scrolling the page etc